# How to install paddlepaddle with no-avx core

Tags: python, docker, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am trying to use `paddleocr` in a docker container and keep getting the error below:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM paddlecloud/paddleocr:2.5-gpu-cuda10.2-cudnn7-85d7d5
```

In docker container after building it:

```py
In [1]: from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
/bin/grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
/bin/grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
Error: Your machine doesn't support AVX, but the installed PaddlePaddle is avx core, you should reinstall paddlepaddle with no-avx core.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError  

..
..
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paddle/fluid/core.py in <module>
    311 if load_noavx:
    312     try:
--> 313         from . import core_noavx
    314         core_noavx.LoDTensor = core_noavx.Tensor
    315 

ImportError: cannot import name 'core_noavx' from 'paddle.fluid' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paddle/fluid/__init__.py)
```

The host is Apple Silicon - M1 Mac

Comment: the latest no-avx version paddlepaddle image was updated 3 years ago on Dockerhub by paddlepaddle, the path is `paddlepaddle/paddle:latest-noavx`

Comment: We are looking into `paddlecloud/paddleocr` docker images, not the `paddlepaddle/paddle`

Answer (score 2):

If your machine does not support avx, you need to install the Paddle package of noavx, you can use the following command to install，**noavx version paddle wheel only support python3.8：**

First use the following command to download the wheel package to the local, and then use python -m pip install [name].whl to install locally ([name] is the name of the wheel package):

cpu and mkl version installed on noavx machine：

```
python -m pip download paddlepaddle==2.3.2 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/noavx/stable.html --no-index --no-deps
```

cpu and openblas version installed on noavx machine：

```
python -m pip download paddlepaddle==2.3.2 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/openblas/noavx/stable.html --no-index --no-deps
```

GPU cuda10.1 version install on noavx machine：

```
python -m pip download paddlepaddle-gpu==2.3.2.post101 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/noavx/stable.html --no-index --no-deps
```

GPU cuda10.2 version install on noavx machine：

```
python -m pip download paddlepaddle-gpu==2.3.2 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/noavx/stable.html --no-index --no-deps
```

To determine whether your machine supports avx, you can use the following command. If the output contains avx, it means that the machine supports avx:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i avx
```

If you want to install the Paddle package with avx and openblas, you can use the following command to download the wheel package to the local, and then use python -m pip install [name].whl to install locally ([name] is the name of the wheel package):

```
python -m pip download paddlepaddle==2.3.2 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/openblas/avx/stable.html --no-index --no-deps
```

---

I found this from [the official website](https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/en/install/quick?docurl=/documentation/docs/en/install/pip/linux-pip_en.html#old-version-anchor-5-Choose%20CPU%2FGPU)